# How to change a github repo's directory to somewhere else?

Tags: xcode, git, github

To avoid being a X-Y problem, this is what happened:

I removed all the pods from the Podfile a few days ago because I didn't need them anymore. Today, I opened up the xcworkspace and see errors. One of them is this:

> diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory

So I first try to solve the issue myself. I tried `pod install`, `pod update`, and lots of other stuff. They all didn't work. So I thought, FINE! I'll delete all the cocoapod-related stuff and start from scratch again! And so I did. But the problem is still there.

Then I downloaded the whole project from github and deleted the broken one. I tried updating cocoapods to the newest version and `pod install`, everything is working in the downloaded project.

After that, I found out that github is not tracking the changes of the downloaded project. It is still tracking the changes of the project in the trash.

I need to find a way to change the project that github is currently tracking to the downloaded project. How do I do this?

P.S. I am an absolute noob of command line interfaces. I cannot remember all those git commands. So if someone can show the solution both using the github (Mac) app and the CLI, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with this:

1. Create a temp folder
2. Move all the stuff in the downloaded project's project folder to the temp folder
3. Delete the downloaded project's project folder, which is now empty
4. Move the deleted project from trash to the original position i.e. "Put Back"
5. Delete the contents of the original project folder
6. Move the stuff in the temp folder into the original project folder, which is now empty
7. Profit!

Answer (score -1):

You might have to add the newly downloaded copy to the SourceTree. 
here are the steps -
SourceTree --> New Repository --> Add existing Local Repo --> Then in the finder window locate the newly downloaded repo.

Now I believe you can see the changes of the new project and commit as well. PFA screenshot.

[image]