# Can I delete the xcodeproj after pod install?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I know that I have to use the .xcworksapce file after I did `pod install`.

But today, I accidentally opened the .xcodeproj file and the whole project broke! And the problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088804/how-to-change-a-github-repos-directory-to-somewhere-else) occurred.

So I want to delete the .xcodeproj file so that I will never break my project by opening it by accident. Can I do that? I didn't try it because I'm afraid I will break my project again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. In fact the `xcworkspace` file use `xcodeproj` file of you project.

The purpose of the `xcworkspace` file is to *make the merge* between your project (and its `xcodeproj`) and the Cocoapods projects (and its `Pods.xcodeproj`).

**EDIT:**

If you want to move your `xcodeproj` to a subfolder (to avoid mistakes), you just have to update your podfile and add:

```
xcodeproj 'subfolder/yourproject.xcodeproj'
```

Then, delete your `xcworkspace`, and do a `pod install`.

Be careful: this works only if your Workspace contains just your project and the pods.

Comment: Then can I move the xcodeproj to another folder (still under the project root directory)? I just want to avoid clicking on it.